# Default root (server.js) file for node.js site on windows azure

Tags: node.js, azure

It seems like Windows Azure expects that your node.js site should run with:

```
node server.js
```

Is there a way to change this command? Specifically, my application's root is `index.js` intead of `server.js`, so I'd prefer that it did:

```
node index.js
```

Anyone know if this is configurable? And even if it is, is it generally considered bad form to have anything other than `server.js`?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I suspect that they're not running `node server.js` but rather `npm start` which defaults to `node server.js` which is why chris's answer is to set the main of your package.json.   You can also set the start script, see npmjs.org for the details.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I tried setting up a package.json file that redefined the 'start' file but it looks like Azure is specifically looking for a server.js file so it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What worked for me was generalhenry's suggestion above:

In package.json, add:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
}
```

Answer (score 8):

None of the solutions above worked for me. Searching for another thing, i've found the solution. You have to set your entrypoint in web.config file which is a xml file. Check this example file (you just have to replace server.js with whatever you want):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>         
      <handlers>
           <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
     </handlers>
      <rewrite>
           <rules>
                <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                     <match url="iisnode"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                    <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="StaticContent">
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="public{{REQUEST_URI}}"/>
                </rule>
                <rule name="DynamicContent">
                     <conditions>
                          <add input="{{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                     </conditions>
                     <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                </rule>
           </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about Azure Web Sites?

Try to set

```
"main": "./index.js"
```

in your package.json file.